# Aegir fails on verify task after import task (Import an existing not aegir site)

Tags: aegir

i'm having many problems with importing sites into aegir hosting system:
here is what i do to import a web site into Aegir:

1. import the directory of the web site into platforms dir
2. import the DB into the db of Aegir
3. create a dir in the sites dir calling it with the domain of the site.
4. cp -r sites/default/* sites/
5. cp -r sites/all/* sites/
6. from Aegir fron-end create the platform giving it the path of the root website dir
7. Aegir verify plaform and detect the site to be imported.
8. Execute the import task with success(i think here is the problem)
9. The task import has a success result (but i think is did not work because the scope is a wrong scope, it takes the main scope of aegir).
10. then the verify task fails, did not create the vhost.d/ , it didn't create drushrc.php file under the sits/.

i think the problem is:
when drush overwrite settings.php and try to store the information of the DB access in the apache environment it fails.
i don't know why...i already made many imports (last one was one week ago), i don't think i changed any thing.

please help me!

Comment: Did you set permissions before adding the platform in Aegir? You should be able to pick through the verify log and find the culprit.

Comment: yes, i already set the permission and the ownership to the user aegir, from log i can't understand what is the problem, its a generic error "Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() 
-
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to make import in the docs, my problem was how to start my import site with my DB, the best way is here:
http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/usage/sites/importing/#importing-a-single-site-manually.
To load your DB you may use `drush @www.site-domain.it sqlc < file-db.sql`
I hope this can help others to make import files.